# Rails: Merit Gem Badge Not Registering or Displaying

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, merit-gem

I set up the following badge which registered in DB:

**merit.rb**

```
Merit::Badge.create!({
id: 1,
name: 'Five Tasks'
custom_fields: { img_url: '/images/badge.gif' }
})
```

I set up the following rule:

**badge_rules.rb**

```
grant_on 'tasks#create', :badge => 'Five Tasks', :temporary => true, :model_name => 'Task' do |task|
task.user_ids.count == 5
end
```

What I wanted to to happen is when the User created 5 tasks they would be issued a badge.

I see entries in the DB in merit_actions and merit_activity_log entries -- but I do not see anything in the badges_sashes which I assume is where they would show when the badge has been issued -- even though I have surpassed the threshold --

Also I am uncertain how to display the badges ---  I am using:

```
<%= current_user.badges %>
```

Right now all I get is brackets -- what I want it to return is an image of the badge ---

Any assistance greatly appreciated.

Comment: Being the badge temporary, as soon as the user creates the 6th task badge will be gone if counting by equals (instead of greater or equal). Anyways, your condition doesn't seem to count what you want, try: `task.user.tasks.count >= 5`.

Comment: That worked.  I changed it to: `grant_on 'tasks#create', :badge => 'Five Tasks', :to => :user do |task| task.user.tasks.count >= 5` and it issued the badge but for the display I am getting a text string: `[#<Merit::Badge id: 1, name: "Five Tasks", level: "1", image: nil, description: nil, custom_fields: {:img_url=>"/images/placeholder.gif"}>]` when I was trying to get an image to show -- what do I need to change -- looks like their is an area already for image (I made it a custom field) -- finally if I want to start over -- do I need to manually clear the DB entries -- thanks for helping

Comment: one additional question -- after the above I tried changing the rule to `grant_on 'tasks#create', :badge => 'Five Tasks', :temporary => true, :to => :user do |task| task.user.tasks.count >= 5` -- restarted the server -- used a new user -- the badge issued as expected -- but when I removed the task it shows removed from the Task table -- but still appears in the merit actions and as an issued badge ---

Answer (score 2):

Are you accessing the badge's custom_fields as a hash? Those custom attributes that you add into custom_fields like img_url, difficulty, color, etc... won't be accessible in simple dot notation ie. `badge.img_url` won't work. Instead you need to do something like  `badge.custom_fields[:img_url]` or `badge.custom_fields[:whatever_custom_attribute]`. Hopefully, the fix will be that simple.

Answer (score 0):

To anyone else with a similar question:  I finally was able to display the badges using the following:

```
<% current_user.badges.each do |badge| %>
<%= image_tag (badge.image) %>
<% end %>
```

Comment: I tried this... the "badges.each do |badge|" finally created the sash... but it still isn't displaying the image when I put the code above. There's no error message either... there's actually nothing at all. I see the sash under sashes and the badge id under the user profile.

Comment: Post your own question with the exact code you are using and I can take a look -- not sure if I will be able to assist but will try -- just provide a link to the post --

Comment: Already did :) Be really thankful if you can help. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21009038/rails-3-2-merit-gem-badge-not-working

Comment: Forgot -- I do not have enough points to comment on yours.  But from your description I would first confirm that you can access the actual image ---  what do you see when you pull up the html code from the actual view?

Comment: Absolutely nothing. I see all the code before and after what you have, and nothing else at all. What's more alarming than not seeing the image, I can't even get it to pull up the name! :)

Comment: Also how does yours work? You have img_url in merit.rb but then you call "badge.image". So how does it even know what that is?

Answer (score 0):

Update Rails 5

You have to specify the custom field param in the view :

## /merit.rb

```
  Merit::Badge.create!(
   id: 2,
   name: "FirstComment",
   description: "Premier commentaire !",
   custom_fields: { category: 'activity', image: 'ITM_02.svg' }
  )
```

## /view

```
<% @profil.badges.each do |badge| %>                               
   <%= image_tag (badge.custom_fields[:image]) %>
<% end %>
```