# Rails 3.2 Merit Gem Badge not Working

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3.2, badge, merit-gem

I've read all the current questions and answers about the Merit gem. And attempted to follow the solution given here [Rails: Merit Gem Badge Not Registering or Displaying](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20511727/rails-merit-gem-badge-not-registering-or-displaying)

initializers/merit.rb:

```
# Use this hook to configure merit parameters
Merit.setup do |config|
  # Check rules on each request or in background
  config.checks_on_each_request = true

  # Define ORM. Could be :active_record (default) and :mongo_mapper and :mongoid
  config.orm = :active_record

  # Define :user_model_name. This model will be used to grand badge if no :to option is given. Default is "User".
  config.user_model_name = "User"

  # Define :current_user_method. Similar to previous option. It will be used to retrieve :user_model_name object if no $
  config.current_user_method = "current_user"
end

# Create application badges (uses https://github.com/norman/ambry)
 # Merit::Badge.create!(

badges = [
  { id: 1, name: 'democratic-society', description: "Voted twice", image: "straight.jpg" }
]
badges.each do |badge|
  Merit::Badge.create!(badge)
end
```

But after 3 hours of trying I've gotten nowhere. I have a badge listed in sashes and my user has that sash id (badges_sashes returns "empty set" though...) but when I try the following code:

application.html.erb:

```
<% current_user.badges.each do |badge| %>
  <%= badge.name %>
  <%= badge.description %>
  <%= image_tag (badge.image) %>
<% end %>
```

badge_rules.rb:

```
grant_on 'posts#vote_up', :badge => 'democratic-society', :to => :user do |post|
  post.votes
end
```

There's no error message whatsoever... so I'm at a bit of a loss on what to do next. I can't even get it to display the badge name. Any help would be appreciated. I get absolutely nothing in the view.

posts_controller.rb:

```
class PostsController < InheritedResources::Base
  before_filter :authenticate_user!, only: [:vote_up]

  def index
    if params[:query].present?
      @posts = Post.tire.search(:query => params[:query])
    else
      @posts = Post.order("created_at desc").paginate(:page => params[:page], :per_page => 15)
    end
  end

  def vote_up
    begin
      current_user.vote_for(@post = Post.find(params[:id]))
      flash[:success] = "Thanks for voting! Be sure to come back to find out the winners!"
      redirect_to [@post]
    rescue ActiveRecord::RecordInvalid
      flash[:error] =  "You have already voted on this one. You're only allowed one vote per song."
      redirect_to [@post]
    end
  end
end
```

development.log:

```
Processing by PostsController#vote_up as HTML
  Parameters: {"authenticity_token"=>"SVWawkgb2hpkAJztuJjIKuIfRww/OjSAZAVpUqKeMOc=", "id"=>"243-worse-than-moe"}
  User Load (1.3ms)  SELECT `users`.* FROM `users` WHERE `users`.`id` = 5 LIMIT 1
  Post Load (1034.1ms)  SELECT `posts`.* FROM `posts` WHERE `posts`.`id` = 243 LIMIT 1
  EXPLAIN (35.6ms)  EXPLAIN SELECT `posts`.* FROM `posts` WHERE `posts`.`id` = 243 LIMIT 1
EXPLAIN for: SELECT  `posts`.* FROM `posts`  WHERE `posts`.`id` = 243 LIMIT 1
+----+-------------+-------+-------+---------------+---------+---------+-------+------+-------+
| id | select_type | table | type  | possible_keys | key     | key_len | ref   | rows | Extra |
+----+-------------+-------+-------+---------------+---------+---------+-------+------+-------+
|  1 | SIMPLE      | posts | const | PRIMARY       | PRIMARY | 4       | const |    1 |       |
+----+-------------+-------+-------+---------------+---------+---------+-------+------+-------+
1 row in set (0.04 sec)

   (0.1ms)  BEGIN

  Vote Exists (99.0ms)  SELECT 1 AS one FROM `votes` WHERE (`votes`.`voteable_id` = BINARY 243 AND `votes`.`voteable_type` = 'Post' AND `votes`.`voter_type` = 'User' AND `votes`.`voter_id` = 5) LIMIT 1
  SQL (152.3ms)  INSERT INTO `votes` (`created_at`, `updated_at`, `vote`, `voteable_id`, `voteable_type`, `voter_id`, `voter_type`) VALUES ('2014-01-09 15:23:45', '2014-01-09 15:23:45', 1, 243, 'Post', 5, 'User')
   (390.5ms)  COMMIT
Redirected to http://liquid-radio.com:3000/posts/243-worse-than-moe
   (0.2ms)  BEGIN
  SQL (47.5ms)  INSERT INTO `merit_actions` (`action_method`, `action_value`, `created_at`, `had_errors`, `processed`, `target_id`, `target_model`, `updated_at`, `user_id`) VALUES ('vote_up', NULL, '2014-01-09 15:23:47', 0, 0, 243, 'posts',
 '2014-01-09 15:23:47', 5)
   (76.0ms)  COMMIT
  Merit::Action Load (0.3ms)  SELECT `merit_actions`.* FROM `merit_actions` WHERE `merit_actions`.`processed` = 0
   (0.1ms)  BEGIN
   (160.6ms)  UPDATE `merit_actions` SET `processed` = 1, `updated_at` = '2014-01-09 15:23:47' WHERE `merit_actions`.`id` = 13
   (99.3ms)  COMMIT
  Post Load (0.1ms)  SELECT `posts`.* FROM `posts` WHERE `posts`.`id` = 243 LIMIT 1
  CACHE (0.0ms)  SELECT `posts`.* FROM `posts` WHERE `posts`.`id` = 243 LIMIT 1
Completed 302 Found in 7214.0ms (ActiveRecord: 2337.7ms)
```

Comment: badges_sashes is the relation between a user's badge list and the badges themselves. For it to work there should be an `INSERT INTO badges_sashes`. How does the controller action look? Can you put the complete Rails log for the action?

Comment: Ok. Added the controller and a log for the action.

Comment: Cool. For first, in the `grant_on` call you don't need to block, as it should always evaluate to `true`. You can omit it and leave only `grant_on 'posts#vote_up', :badge => 'democratic-society', :to => :user`.

Comment: Does `@post.user` return the user you want to grant a badge to?

Comment: Which version of merit are you using? Can you post the contents of your whole `merit.rb` file?

Comment: Complete merit.rb posted. Merit version is 1.7.0. @post.user returns nothing. I got rid of the block as well and put what you said but it didn't change anything. Also tried "to => :current_user" and I get: "undefined method `_sash' for true:TrueClass"

Comment: If you take out the `:to` option, it should grant it to the current user who votes up. At that point we know merit is working. Now if `@post.user` returns nothing there's no user to grant a badge to, and that's why it's failing. With current code, if you tie up the relation between the upvoted post and any one user, or define a dummy user method in the `Post` model that returns any user, you will see that that will be the badged one. merit does nothing when no target user is found (and it should log the encountered nil).

Comment: Ok. Removed the :to option and it worked. Thanks. (btw you should add something to your gem's page explaining how to display things) So you're saying that if I did like "def user... post.user = current_user" then it should work? Now I just have to work backwards because what I *really* want is to give the badge upon 2 votes. So I guess I have to create the dummy user so that I can use the :to field and put the block back wit post.votes == "2"?

Comment: Indeed. By "dummy user" I assume you are meaning the author of the post, which, if it was set, would be working. Thanks for the suggestion on improving the README. Pull Requests in Github very welcome! :)

Comment: Oh no. I guess I haven't explained well enough. The current user, not the author, should get the badge for voting up. It works by removing the to: field, but don't I need that to specify 2 votes? The author should get no badge. I can't quite figure out why it doesn't give the badge to the current user without removing the to: field... since it obviously seems to know who the badge should go to...

Comment: `:to` option is a method which is called on the target object (`@post` in your case), see https://github.com/tute/merit#defining-badge-rules. If you want it to be granted to the current_user, that's the default behavior, you don't need to specify that option. If we can improve the documentation to reflect that I'm happy to hear how!

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/44952/discussion-between-mystic-cola-and-tutec)

Comment: Better README: https://github.com/tute/merit#table-of-contents. Thanks for your feedback!