# Merit Gem with Rails 3.2... nothing displays

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3.2, badge, merit-gem

I want to use the Merit gem but... it displays nothing. I've already read this [Rails: Merit Gem Badge Not Registering or Displaying](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20511727/rails-merit-gem-badge-not-registering-or-displaying) and this [Rails 3.2 Merit Gem Badge not Working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21009038/rails-3-2-merit-gem-badge-not-working) but I don't understand why it doesn't work.

merit.rb

```
    # Use this hook to configure merit parameters
Merit.setup do |config|
  # Check rules on each request or in background
  # config.checks_on_each_request = true

  # Define ORM. Could be :active_record (default) and :mongoid
  config.orm = :active_record

  # Add application observers to get notifications when reputation changes.
  # config.add_observer 'MyObserverClassName'

  # Define :user_model_name. This model will be used to grand badge if no
  # `:to` option is given. Default is 'User'.
   config.user_model_name = 'User'

  # Define :current_user_method. Similar to previous option. It will be used
  # to retrieve :user_model_name object if no `:to` option is given. Default
  # is "current_#{user_model_name.downcase}".
   config.current_user_method = 'current_user'
end

# Create application badges (uses https://github.com/norman/ambry)
badge_id = 0
[{
  id: (badge_id = badge_id+1),
  name: 'Timide',
  description: '1 comment',
  level: 1
}, {
  id: (badge_id = badge_id+1),
  name: 'Bavard',
  description: '3 comments',
  level: 3
},{
  id: (badge_id = badge_id+1),
  name: 'Pipelette',
  description: '5 comments',
  level: 5
}].each do |attrs|
  Merit::Badge.create! attrs
end
```

badge_rules.rb

```
module Merit
  class BadgeRules
    include Merit::BadgeRulesMethods

    def initialize
      # If it creates user, grant badge
      # Should be "current_user" after registration for badge to be granted.
      # grant_on 'users#create', badge: 'just-registered', to: :itself

      # If it has 1 comment, grant commenter-1 badge
      grant_on 'comments#index', badge: 'Timide', level: 1 do |comment|
        comment.user.comments.count == 1
      end
```

comments_controller.rb

```
class CommentsController < ApplicationController
  before_filter :authenticate_user!, except: [:index, :show]

  # GET /comments
  # GET /comments.json
  def index
    @comments = Comment.all

    respond_to do |format|
      format.html # index.html.erb
      format.json { render json: @comments }
    end
  end
```

And I use current_user.badges to display in my view.

Thanks for your help !

Comment: I finally found the solution. I replaced this line : 
 `grant_on comments#index', badge: 'Timide', level: 1 do |comment| comment.user.comments.count == 1 end`

By 

`grant_on 'comments#create', badge: 'Timide', level: 1, to: :user`

And it works very well :)